# Having + object + Past participle and having + object + bare infinitive

Tags: grammar, active-voice, grammar-myths, active-vs-passive

What is the difference in these two sentences. I am quite confused

> *The minister had eggs thrown at him. [past participle]*

> *The minister had a woman throw eggs at him. [bare infinitive]*

I think the first sentence is conveying the experience of a minister but I am not sure about the second sentence.

In what other ways these sentences can be written and what are these sentences conveying?

Comment: The second could mean either 'he had eggs thrown at him by a woman', or 'he got a woman to throw eggs at another man'.

Comment: @Kate Bunting..It's a poor sentence then because of unclear meaning. What about the first sentence?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the first sentence.